# Swift: show Date() in other language

Tags: swift, date

Is there a way to show date in a language other than English (especially the day in a week) in Swift?

I already have this `DateFormatter` to show the day in a week, but it only shows it in English:

```
var today = Date()

static let weekDayFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")
        formatter.dateFormat = "E"
        return formatter
    }()
```

If I write `Text("\(today, formatter: Self.weekDayFormat)")`, it will show "Sat".

However, I need it to show it in Chinese. Even if I tried set `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")` and other identifier of Chinese, it always output an English result. I think it might just be that the English acronym of weekdays is commonly recognized, but my client wants it to show Chinese.

Comment: Have you tried to set `formatter.locale` to the locale of the desired language?

Comment: @MartinR Do you know why `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols` returns  ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"] and `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).weekdaySymbols` returns ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]? I have checked Calendar.current value and it returns `gregorian (current)`

Comment: @CharlotteL. Your question is not clear. Are you trying to show today weekday localized? What are the desired input and expected output? edit your question and show it.

Comment: @MartinR More precisely speaking, even though some of the formats contains other languages, the formatter for the locale that I want to use still uses English weekdaySymbols.

Comment: @CharlotteL. You can change the language of the current calendar using locale `var calendar = Calendar.current`
`calendar.locale = .init(identifier: "pt")` then use `calendar.weekdaySymbols`  // ["domingo", "segunda-feira", "terça-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira", "sexta-feira", "sábado"]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you create an answer and provide a demonstration? I am a bit confused that: do I add these codes in the `weekDayFormat` in my code? I have tried that, but it does not change the language (neither for "pt" nor "zh"). Also, I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @CharlotteL. check my post below

Comment: @CharlotteL. If you would like to use the device current locale just remove the locale from the code or change it to current  `fformatter.locale = .current`

Comment: also for weekday standalone dateFormat you should use `formatter.dateFormat = "ccc"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(Formatter.weekDay.string(from: Date())).padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension Formatter {
    static let weekDay: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        // you can use a fixed language locale
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")
        // or use the current locale
        // formatter.locale = .current
        
        // and for standalone local day of week use ccc instead of E
        formatter.dateFormat = "ccc"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still shows "Sat" if I set `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")` or `formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt")` (and also `formatter.dateFormat = "ccc"`). Does it work in your environment? Is it something wrong wth mine?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcwph02zog2gh55/weekday.jpg?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

## Localising date depending of the language settings of the iPhone/iPad

This is an interesting case. Did you take the example from Hacking with Swift? ;)
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-format-text-inside-text-views

I use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` because preferred by Apple as in WWDC:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10160/

[image: preferred date formatter for localisation]

I had the same problem, it would not work with the locale parameter inside the static var and I solved it in this way:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {

    var today: String {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")
        //or formatter.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent 
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("E")
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }

    // or edited from Leo Dabus
    static let weekDay: DateFormatter = {
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh")
                    // or formatter.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent 
                    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("E")
                    return formatter
            }()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(today) \(Self.weekDay.string(from: Date()))")
        }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}
```

#### Autoupdate depending of setting

`formatter.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent` will auto update according to changes to the current language setting of the simulator or device in setting/general/language.
But don't forget to add those languages in your project!

- In the project navigator (View > Navigator > Show Project Navigator), select your project at the top.
- In the editor displayed, select your project at the top of the list on the left.
- Switch to the Info tab.
- In the Localizations slice, press the add (+) button and select the language from the list.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97252?answerId=295557022#295557022
[image: Xcode screenshot]